# Using many sql connection in one code?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have an ASP.NET web application which is connected to SQL Server.

I have used three connections for each SQL operation. It works very well, however I think this is not an efficient way to do things - can this be written better than it is?

```
public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection co = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TextConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TextConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TextConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (co)
        {
            co.Open();
            SqlCommand cm = co.CreateCommand();
            cm.CommandText = "select...";
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        co.Close();

        using (con)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmv = con.CreateCommand();
            cmv.CommandText = "insert...";

            cmv.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        con.Close();

        using (con2)
        {
            con2.Open();
            SqlCommand cmf = con2.CreateCommand();
            cmf.CommandText = "delete from...";
            cmf.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        con2.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can change the command text and execute again as many times as you want within one connection

Comment: What you are trying to acheive ?

Comment: No harm doing so but also no need to. Use one connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     SqlConnection co = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TextConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (co)
            {
                co.Open();
                SqlCommand cm = co.CreateCommand();
                cm.CommandText = "select...";
                cm.CommandText += " insert..."; 
                cm.CommandText += " delete from...";
                cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            co.Close();              
        }
```

you can use like this.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the same connection string for each connection? Why do you need three connections? Why not just open and close the same one?

As long as the connection string is the same, you only need one connection.

Answer (score 2):

*In general* you should prefer to create and open a connection object as close to where you make use of it as possible, and dispose of it as soon as possible afterwards (preferably by making use of a `using` statement). Connection pooling will take care of ensuring you only actually create a limited number of *real* connections to the server, despite the large number of `SqlConnection` objects your code may seem to create.

Within a *single* method, however, it is reasonable to use a single connection object:

```
public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TextConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection co = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            co.Open();
            using(SqlCommand cm = co.CreateCommand())
            {
              cm.CommandText = "select...";
              cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            using(SqlCommand cmv = co.CreateCommand())
            {
              cmv.CommandText = "insert...";
              cmv.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            using(SqlCommand cmf = co.CreateCommand())
            {
              cmf.CommandText = "delete from...";
              cmf.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(You don't need to explicitly close the connection object, the `Dispose` (within the `using` is equivalent)

Answer (score 2):

1. No use declaring/creating multiple connections when you would be using only one at a time. You can do with just one.
2. Declare variable as close as possible to its first use, and with minimum scope manageable.
3. Make things modular and reusable as far as possible.
4. No need to explicitly close the connection, since the IDisposable interface implementation (and `using` block) does it anyways. But there is no harm in explicitly closing it.

---

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExecuteNonQuery("select...", null);         // why??
    ExecuteNonQuery("insert...", null);
    ExecuteNonQuery("delete from...", null);
}

protected void ExecuteNonQuery(string query, SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    using (SqlConnection co = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TextConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        co.Open();
        SqlCommand cm = co.CreateCommand();
        cm.CommandText = query;
        if (parameters != null) cm.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this.

```
        SqlConnection co = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TextConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           sb.AppendLine(" Select statement.. ");
           sb.AppendLine(" Insert statement ");
           sb.AppendLine(" delete statement ");
            using (co)
            {
                co.Open();
                SqlCommand cm = co.CreateCommand();
                cm.CommandText = sb.Tostring();
                cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            co.Close();              
        }
```